# Manager property is not available for Full Text Search (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I had created a web part on MOSS 2007 which displays a organizational chart by searching (Full Text) the user profiles.

To identify the subordinates of a user, I used to search for users with the particular user in Manager property. The query looked like this:

```
SELECT AccountName, PreferredName, Manager, WorkEmail FROM scope()  WHERE ("SCOPE" = 'People') AND Manager = 'domain\parent_user'
```

But, the same query does not run in SharePoint 2010 as Manager crawled property does not exists. 
So, I created a new crawled property and mapped it to People:Manager(Text) now, the Manager property is always empty.

Even a full crawl after clearing the indexes also not helping.

Can anyone please help me in getting manager information in Full Text Search?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** I tried mapping the crawled property with ows_Manager(Text) property also, still the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling a little, I got it working!

The new crawled property mapped to `People:Manager(text)` started giving values in search result by following the below steps:

1. Check `Indexed` checkbox in `Manager` User Profile property edit page
2. Reset crawl index
3. Full crawl again